# Does Piwik transfer personal data to third party servers?

Tags: php, statistics, web, matomo, web-statistics

I'm using [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) for my multiple websites. Installed it on shared server.

I wonder, is there any possibility that this tool transfers my websites' statistics to third party servers such as application owner's servers? How can I check this tool for this reason?

Comment: There is detailed information about privacy on the project page, I wonder how you could miss that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is never shared with anyone. Here is the explanation from [Piwik's privacy page](http://piwik.org/privacy/)

> Piwik ensures the Privacy of your Users and Analytics data. When using
>   Piwik, YOU keep control of your data, nobody else does. Your data is
>   stored in your own Mysql Database, and logs or reports data will never
>   be sent to other servers by Piwik.

Comment: Ok. lets say it's true info, but, Is there any way to check this application for connections to other servers?